# Vuejs и template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть вот такой код

```
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    el: '#app',
    template: '<p>111111</p>',
    data: {
        items: [],
    },
    created: function () {
        this.fetchData();
    },
    watch: {
        // call again the method if the route changes
        '$route': 'fetchData'
    },
    methods: {
      fetchData: function () {
          var requestUrl = this.$router.options.base + this.$router.history.current.fullPath;
          var self = this;
          this.$http.get( requestUrl ).then( response => this.$options.template = '<strong>22222</strong>' ); //not working :(

            // this.$options.template = '<strong>22222</strong>' // working

      }
    }
});
```

Т.е. получается при изменении роута отправляется ajax запрос, и я хочу динамически менять шаблон, но ничего не получается, ошибок нет, просто выводит начальный вариант

```
<p>111111</p>
```

Собственно почему так и как можно это сделать ?

Comment: ну вероятно потому, что вы теперь должны запустить рендеринг, и вообще это какой-то  топорный способ, воспользуйтесь vue-route

Comment: Я хочу динамически менять template/data, т.е. ответ от сервера будет примерно таким {template: '', data: ''} или просто {'здесь код компонента(Single File Components)'} Я изучаю vuejs всего пару дней. Пробовал через Vue.compile( response.data ).render. Но так у меня свойства не доступны почему то.

Comment: Скорее всего такое работать не будет, не могу понять зачем ты пытаешься менять содержимое шаблона динамически ? Ты должен менять данные в шаблоне, но никак не шаблон. В твоем случае нужно тогда создать столько шаблонов сколько нужно и подключить их, а затем по прилету определенных данных прятать одни и отображать другие

Comment: У меня проект разбит на модули, в каждом модуле свои файлы представлений/скрипты/стили. Допустим есть модуль на стороне сервера Каталог, мне нужно отрисовать страницу с таблицой, я использую https://vuetifyjs.com/components/data-tables в качестве основы. Так вот именно эту часть кода я хочу отдавать с сервера. Т.е. собираться все будет на клиенте, но сами файлы шаблона(компоненты vuejs) будут отдаваться севером и физически находиться в папке с модулем, а компилиться на клиенте уже с помощью vuejs. Как-то так.

Answer (score 1):

Кажется в вашем варианте стоит использовать vue-router и ленивую загрузку путей. При переходе на определённый путь будет загружаться соответствующая минисборка из необходимых компонентов.